# Forgetful Functor $MonCat\rightarrow Cat$ preserves filtered colimits?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, limits-and-colimits

Did not get an answer from the Stack Exchange.

Let $MonCat$ and $Cat$ denote the 2-categories of monoidal categories with strict monoidal functors and small categories, respectively.

There is a forgetful functor $Forget:MonCat\rightarrow Cat$ Does this preserve (filtered) colimits? I am thinking of 2-colimits in MonCat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  Intuitively, this is because all the operations of a monoidal category are "finitary".

One way to prove this formally is that the 2-monad for monoidal categories can be given a presentation in the category of finitary 2-monads, hence it is finitary (which is equivaent to its forgetful functor preserving filtered colimits).  A good reference for presentations of 2-monads is Steve Lack's [A 2-categories companion](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702535).